# sending list content from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

guys i want to send a list content from servlet to jsp but it always gives me null despite what i entered .. here is my code

inside the jsp

```
<body>
<form action="ServerSide" method="post">
Enter list Size:<input type="text" name="listsize">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<% List lst = (List) request.getAttribute("MyList"); %>
<%= lst %>
</body>
```

inside the servlet

```
String listSize = request.getParameter("listsize");
    int size = Integer.parseInt(listSize);
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        list.add("test"+i);
    }
    request.setAttribute("MyList", list);
```

Comment: Instead of `request` try using `session`. Like `session.setAttribute("MyList", list);`

Comment: i did .. but it gives me the last(stored) input not the current one

Comment: You also have to store your object in the session, not in the request, to retrieve it from the session (request.getSession().setAttribut(...)). How do you call your jsp from the servlet?

Comment: i am not calling it .. how to do that ??

Comment: @memomemo That's because of existing session. You have to `invalidate` properly. See my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769014/sending-list-content-from-servlet-to-jsp/35769273#35769273) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String listSize = request.getParameter("listsize");
    int size = Integer.parseInt(listSize);
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        list.add("test"+i);
    }
    request.setAttribute("MyList", list);
request.getRequestDispathcer("JSP FILE NAME").forward(request, response);
```

Use above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before setting value in session,

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
   session.invalidate();
}
```

Then set the session attribute,

```
session.setAttribute("MyList", list);
```